# Restore a 1.2GB bak file but database size is not that much

Tags: sql-server

As mentioned, I have restore a 1.2GB bak file in MSSQL v18.5.1. After I monitor the database and all table size is not that much. Only cost about 300MB.
[image: bak file size]
[image: Database size]

Can someone help and explain to me? I have do some research and still don't know why. Thanks!

Comment: As a guess, the original backup was mostly transaction log and that got applied to the database as it was restored? (But I can't remember exactly how that works exactly)

Comment: @Rup When I restored the database from bak file, the transaction log will not be restored also?

Comment: Multiple backups in a single backup file? I doubt we really have enough information here to do more than hazard guesses. This isn't, however, about programming and is off topic for Stack Overflow. It should be on [dba.se], but will likely need more information or several comments answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I'm apologize to my question without found this post which this post has completely resolve my problem.

[Why is SQL Server backup so much larger than the DB files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085402/why-is-sql-server-backup-so-much-larger-than-the-db-files)

Anyone who facing this issue can refer to this link. Hope help someone else!